# Преобразование координат в изометрии

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

Пытаюсь нарисовать изометрическую карту для игры. Имею следующие параметры:

- Ширина ячейки
- Высота ячейки
- Количество ячеек по ширине
- Количество ячеек по высоте

Карта хранится в двумерном массиве, ячейки обходятся вложенным циклом. На шаге цикла - индекс ячейки по `x` и по `y`. Если речь об обычной 2d-карте, то координата ячейки - это `[x * cellWidth; y * cellHeight]`.

Планирую сделать функцию для перевода из экранных координат в изометрические. То есть, в цикле получаю те же `[x * cellWidth; y * cellHeight]`, передаю их в функцию и получаю изометрические координаты с нужным смещением, чтобы ячейки перекрывали друг друга, как это бывает в изометрии. Эту же функцию планирую использовать для вывода обычных линий на экране. Например, чтобы вывести верхнюю границу карты, получаю 2 точки:

```
[0; 0]
[mapWidth * cellWidth; 0]
```

Передаю обе точки в функцию преобразования координат и затем по результирующим координатам рисую линию. И хотя в экранном пространстве это была горизонтальная линия, в финальном выводе линия будет наклонной.

Итак, вопроса всего два:

1. Возможно ли обойтись одной функцией преобразования координат для вывода и ячеек с перекрытием, и обычных линий в изометрическом пространстве?
2. Хватит ли имеющихся данных, чтобы написать такую функцию преобразования (размеры ячейки и количество ячеек по ширине и высоте)?

И если да, то подскажите формулу для преобразования координат.

[image: Пример перекрытия ячеек]

Comment: Что за перекрытие ячеек?

Comment: @MBo, прикрепил изображение. Означает наложение ячеек друг на друга. По сути это прямоугольные изображения с прозрачными участками по углам.

Comment: Покажите набросок, как отсчитываются ваши координаты. [Пример для случая](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035096/), когда начало вверху посередине (и углы там не 120, кажется)